# How to display users who joined the chat room (socket)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, chat

I'm making a NodeJs,React and socket.io chat-application.. its working fine.. but I want to display the users who joined the room on my webpage.. is it possible?>

Here is my code (Server side)

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const {getAllUsers} = require('./config/Database.js');
const path = require('path');


app.use(cors());
dotenv.config();


getAllUsers()
.then (data=>{
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(err =>{
  console.log(err);
})



const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    // origin: "http://localhost:3001",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
    console.log(`User with ID: ${socket.id} joined room: ${data}`);
    
  });

  

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    try {
      io.to(data.room).emit("receive_message", data);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      
    };
    
    
  });


  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User Disconnected", socket.id);
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

here is my client side, I also have a chat.js file but i think the chatRoom.js one is where i have to make changes.. >

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useState } from "react";
import Chat from "./Chat";




const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

    function ChatRoom() {
      const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
      const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
      const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false);
    
      const joinRoom = () => {
        if (username !== "" && room !== "") {
          socket.emit("join_room", room);
          setShowChat(true);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
    
            <div className="joinChatContainer">
              <h3>Join A Chat</h3>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="John..."
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setUsername(event.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Room ID..."
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setRoom(event.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <button onClick={joinRoom}>Join A Room</button>
            </div>
            
            <Chat socket={socket} username={username} room={room} />
          
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default ChatRoom;
```